# Keep creating an extra empty page on "next"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem with a tool built in HTML and Angular.js.
Basically the site is built the way that it should store 15 entries on a page, then you press "Next" and the next 15 entries should be listed, which works fine.

BUT, when you are at the last page (when there is no more entries) it automatically creates another "Next page" which is empty.

I am a newbie on Angular.js and i am stuck right now.

```
    $scope.loadCharters = function () {
        var keys = [];
        _.each($scope.sessions, function (sess) {
            sess.checked && keys.push(sess.key);
        });
        charterFactory.getChartersBySession(keys, function (charters) {
            $scope.charters = charters;
            $scope.filterCharters();
        }, 15, ($scope.page - 1) * 15);
    };

    $scope.nextPage = function () {
        if ($scope.charters && $scope.charters.length) {
            $scope.page++;     
            $scope.loadCharters();
        }
    };
```

This is the functions that should list the pages (15 entries / page). But i dont understand why it keeps creating +1 empty?

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: And can you show template? What is the condition for next button to be shown?

Comment: You need some code to check if you are at the last page. Now you just increment the page, and refetch. The fetching will then start after your last record, and return empty.
Introduce a variable so you know you are on your last page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a html template somewhere that has an element with the attribute:

```
ng-click="nextPage()"
```

on it to capture the click. You need to add another attribute to that element that looks like:

```
ng-disabled="page*15 >= charters.length"
```

this should disable the element from being clicked when you're on the last page.